# Finding line number info from a PC register value

Tags: c, debugging, gdb, embedded

I have a SPARC embedded executable built with debugging symbols. I ran this executable on a machine using a debug monitor, but without a debugger. The program crashed (segfault) and I found out the value of the PC register from the monitor (note: not a debugger). If I were using gdb at the time I would've known which line number it got stuck in. However, I wasn't using GDB at the time.

I want to find out what C line number the PC value corresponds to. What tool or gdb command can I use to find this out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [this part of the documentation](http://www.chemie.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/use/info/gdb/gdb_8.html#SEC50) you can use the `info` command:

```
info line *0x63ff
```

That gets the line information for the code at address `0x63ff`. Replace the address in the example with your own.

Comment: This works. I should've checked the GDB documentation more carefully. I didn't think GDB was the right tool for this.... thanks!

Comment: This approach works fine sometimes, but not always.  It won't work if you have shared libraries or if you are using ASLR.  In those cases you need to know both the PC and the mappings; then maybe some invocation of `objdump` would work ok.